# Can't locate notifypy module for some reason

Tags: python

Every time I try to run my code, I get the error "No module named 'notifypy'".

Code below:

```
from notifypy import Notify

notification = Notify()
notification.title = 'big sleez has awoken'
notification.message = 'hes pissed dude'
notification.send
```

I'm not really sure how to import modules properly. I just copied the libs example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Do you have this ```notifypy``` module installed?

Comment: Have you installed `notifypy` before trying to import it?

Comment: `notifypy` is a third-party module.  It is not a standard part of Python; you have to install it yourself.  Did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Install [notify-py](https://pypi.org/project/notify-py/) first on your local. Try this on your terminal/command prompt:

```
python -m pip install notify-py
```

or

```
pip install notify-py
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-notify
```